# Как сместить график в точку -4 matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

У меня есть функция, которая отрисовывает кривую распределения

```
head = 0.4 / otkl
left = mexp - 3 * otkl
right = mexp + 3 * otkl
arr = np.arange(left, right, 0.001)
plt.plot(arr, norm.pdf(arr, 0, 1))
plt.show()
```

Так вот, мне надо сделать так, чтобы график начинал строиться не из точки x=0, а из точки x=-4 (ну в данном случае). Как это можно сделать? Также интересно, как можно задать высоту графика?

Comment: Давайте уже приводите весь код - с импортом библиотек и с выставлением значений `otkl`, `mexp`. Нужно догадаться, что у вас там?

Comment: Впрочем, я и так ответил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем суть была в том, что в документации я проглядел (или там реально не было) параметр отклонения

```
@staticmethod
    def paint_normal_distribution(mexp, otkl):
        """
        Строит график кривой нормального распределения
        """
        head = 0.4 / otkl
        left = mexp - 3 * otkl
        right = mexp + 3 * otkl
        arr = np.arange(left, right, 0.001)
        plt.plot(arr, norm.pdf(arr, mexp, otkl))
        print("Левая граница = {}, правая граница = {}, высота = {}".format(left, right, head))
        plt.show()
```

mexp - мат. ожидание смещает график на определённую позицию по x
otkl - отклонение, как раз показывает, на сколько график должен быть ограничен по высоте

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку в вашем коде есть две неизвестных величины `otkl` и `mexp`, я просто выставил их в такие значения, чтобы `left` получилось `-4`. И не совсем понятно, что вы имели в виду под "выставить высоту фигуры" - сделать другие значения шкалы или сам график сделать другого размера? Если график другого размера, то через `plt.figure`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(3,5))
otkl = 1
mexp = -1
head = 0.4 / otkl
left = mexp - 3 * otkl
right = mexp + 3 * otkl
arr = np.arange(left, right, 0.001)
plt.plot(arr, norm.pdf(arr, 0, 1))
plt.show()
```

[image: norm-pdf]

Comment: Да, согласен, не очень конструктивно расписал
mexp - мат ожидание
otkl - стандартное отклонение
Высота у графика должна быть 0,22 по формуле 0,4/отклонение, но он выстраивает график по высоте 0,4

Comment: @Resistance杀杀杀 Я позже тогда подумаю, пока некогда. Но вы бы всё-таки привели свои значения этих переменных, что получается в итоге и что вы хотите, а то сейчас сложно понять. Всё это добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Я добавил ответ, собственно проблема была в документации или во мне, потому что не увидел то, что метод pdf принимает ещё стандартное отклонение, которое задаёт высоту. Смещение графика строится по мат. ожиданию, там было в документации написано, собственно, я так и сделал